# ReCaptcha V2 returns False even though checked

Tags: php, html, recaptcha

Having a problem with ReCaptcha. Even if checkbox is checked, it still returns false. I have triple checked my keys and happy they are correct. I am using code based on that successfully used on another of my sites. Cannot see what is wrong.

For ease of reference, I have copied all the relevant coding. Hopefully someone will see straight away what I've done wrong.

Form Code:

```
<form name="contactform" method="post" action="send_form_email.php">
<table width="450px">
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="first_name">First Name *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="Please enter your first name" maxlength="50" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top"">
  <label for="last_name">Last Name *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input type="text" name="last_name" placeholder="Please enter your surname" maxlength="50" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="email">Email Address *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Please enter your email address" maxlength="80" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="telephone">Telephone Number</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input type="tel" name="telephone" placeholder="Please enter your phone number" maxlength="30" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="comments">Comments *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <textarea  name="comments" maxlength="1000" cols="25" rows="6"></textarea>
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center"><div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LejdlwUAAAAAHb5qaNIhfDzxL1i9a9sCyw8dLzD"></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">  <br> <a href="https://www.freecontactform.com/email_form.php" class="visuallyhidden">Email Form</a>
 </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Code from the PHP:

```
<?php

// Code from ReCaptcha evaluation:
$email;$comment;$captcha;
        if(isset($_POST['email'])){
          $email=$_POST['email'];
        }if(isset($_POST['comment'])){
          $email=$_POST['comment'];
        }if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])){
          $captcha=$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
        }
        if(!$captcha){
          echo '<h2>Please check the the captcha form.</h2>';
          exit;
        }
        $secretKey = "************************************";
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        $response=file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".$secretKey."&response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$ip);
        $responseKeys = json_decode($response,true);
        if(intval($responseKeys["success"]) !== 1) {
          echo '<h2>You are a spammer ! Your form has been rejected.</h2>';
        } else
// End Code from ReCaptcha evaluation.
```

Many Thanks
Tim

Comment: Do `var_dump($responseKeys);` to see the error.

Comment: Thanks. That returns "Null".

What does that tells us?

Comment: if `-disable-url-fopen-wrapper` is set on your server you cannot use `file_get_contents()`. Can you verify that `file_get_contents` is working?

Comment: If file_get_contents is enabled, I believe it returns null on anything that is not a 200 response, possible 2xx response but you'll get better usage with using curl

Comment: OK. Thanks. I have just checked the other domain where the form WAS working, and discovered that it isn't. It appears to have the same problem.

Presumably, then, I need to enable the "url-fopen-wrapper"? How do I do that? I can only assume that a server update at some point has changed this setting.

Comment: OK. Managed to answer my own question! Seems to be down to the PHP version running on the server. I had set it to 7.0.30 and, despite the "allow-url-fopen" being set to on, it must have been causing the rejection. I have now set it back to version 5.4.16 (the OS Vendor version), and the ReCaptcha form now works!

Next question, therefore, is how can I utilise the latest PHP version AND still have the ReCaptcha form working?

Comment: Sorry @Tim I didn't get the alert that you replied to this topic. You are much better using curl as you'll run into many issues using that function

Comment: Not come across curl. Is there a resource for use with ReCaptcha that you can point me to, please?